# Deserialise JSON using a JSON schema

Tags: python, json, validation, jsonschema

I have some JSON that Im decoding using `json.loads()` to python object.

```
data = json.loads(request.body)
```

Therefore data looks something like this:

```
data = {
   'fullName': 'John Smith',
   'dob': '1970-01-01T00:00:00',
}
```

Given I also have a JSON schema definition:

```
schema = {
    "title": "Person",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "fullName": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "dob": {
           "type": "string",
           "format": "date-time"
        }
    },
}
```

There are lots of library that will validate that "data" conforms to "schema" rules.

e.g Using https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jsonschema

```
from jsonschema import validate

//raises exception if data is invalid.
validate(data, schema)
```

However `jsonschema.validate()` doesn't return the "cleaned" data for me to use.

My question is is there a python library I can use to deserialise JSON to python using JSON schema for validation?

```
output = {
    'fullName': 'John Smith',
    'dob': datetime.datetime(2050, 1, 1, 0, 0),
}
```

Any tips or suggestions will be appreciated. Many Thanks.

Comment: I already had a look at http://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html
Ideally I would like continue using JSON schema to define rules.